# Python tkinter Progressbar for svn update

Tags: python, svn, tkinter, time, progress-bar

I need a progressbar to show the user the progress of the svn updates, but I do not know how to do this simultaneously to the svn update, I can only do it afterwards and then only indirectly, but if I let the progressbar show after the update , then I need twice the time and that's not the point.

Please help me how to update the progressbar while the update is running which needs a variable time and please give me an example of what you mean

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, dictionary_with_paths):
        self.dictionary_with_paths = {}
        self.progressbar = Progressbar(range_end)           

    def update_local_tag_folder(self):
        os.system('svn update '+ self.dictionary_with_paths['local_tags'])

    def update_progressbar(self, current_value):
        """
           Progressbar() is a class that simply create an tk() frame with 1 
           label, an progressbar and a button and it need an start value and 
           an end point, the end point comes with an parameter in the class, 
           the start/current count are given from method 
           Progressbar().set_current_Value(current_value)
        """
        self.progressbar.set_current_value(current_Value)
        self.progressbar.update()

    def get_update_progress_and_update_bar(self):
        """
           here is the point i have no idea how can i can get an list of 
           files or any other useful things
        """
        SVN_list = os.system('svn ls -v -R '+ \
                            self.dictionary_with_paths['repository_trunk'])
        """
           Console shows an list with all files, but i cant read the lines to 
           count that
        """
```

I also thought about using subprocessor but I do not know exactly how to read the output of SVN_list so that I can count the lines

**SOLVED:**
Fixed problem, I have created new threads in which I can once run the svn update and in another I can simultaneously create the Progressbar and let it run ...

short snapshot what i mean...

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Yeeeehaaa():

def mymethod1(self, arg):
    for e in range(0,arg):
        print('Yeeeee')
        sleep(1)

def mymethod2(self, arg):
    for e in range(0,arg):
        print('haaaaa')
        sleep(1)

def start_threads(self):
    thread = Thread(target=mymethod1, args=(10,))
    thread.start()
    thread = Thread(target=mymethod2, args=(10,))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    thread.join()
```

Comment: You should consider sharing some code of how you are currently getting the progress of svn and how you call svn.

Comment: have edited it, now you see in a nutshell, as I call svn and think to read it out, I think you in advance